# How to solve object has no attribute 'action' error?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to pass some profile information via the django rest api to my front end. When doing so I encountering the following issue:

```
'ProfileAPI' object has no attribute 'action'
```

```
class ProfileAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
  permission_classes = [
    permissions.IsAuthenticated, 
  ]
  serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

  queryset = Profile.objects.all()

  def get_queryset(self):
    if self.action == 'list':
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
    return self.queryset
```

Im currently a little bit lost to trace down the problem.

Comment: This happens because you didn't defined any ```action``` attribute in your ```ProfileAPI``` class.

Comment: `generics.RetrieveAPIView` Used for read-only endpoints to represent a [**single model instance**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview). Not sure what you are trying to achieve with `self.action == 'list'` with in the `get_queryset` method. If you want to return collection of model instances then consider using [ListAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview)

Comment: where `action` is supposed to come from ?
is it a query parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if not hasattr(self,'action'):
        return None
    if self.action == 'list':
        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
    return self.queryset
```

Comment: Can you please give more details about your answer? I want to understand why in some cases this class could contain the ```action``` attribute and why in some others don't